# How to make mutable generic functions in F#

Tags: f#

While in the FSI, I'd like to "easily" replace/mock a function.  This is great for rapid iteration and works nicely unless the function is generic.  For example:

```
// ... deep in some DLL
let int_op (x:int) = "hello "+(x.ToString())
let mutable realInt_op = int_op   // OK!

let generic_op (x:'a) = "hello "+(x.ToString())
let mutable real_op = generic_op   // Err: Value restriction!

// ... later in FSI
let mock_op x = "Waaaaasup "+(x.ToString())
do 
    real_op <- mock_op
```

So, is there a nice way to "quickly" mock generic functions?

Comment: I usually just shadow it (just do another `let`). Are you actually capturing `real_op` inside another value in FSI and you want that to be updated too?

Comment: @jwosty. Yeah, I want to monkey-patch all real_op <- mock_op.

Answer (score 1):

I can see 3 possibilities. 
As Jwotsy mentioned you can just shadow if you want to do this.

```
let intop (x:int) = "hello "+(x.ToString())
let mutable realIntop = intop

let inline genericop (x:'a) = "hello "+(x.ToString())
let realop = genericop 

let mockop x = "Waaaaasup "+(x.ToString())
do 
    let realop = mockop
    realop "" |> ignore //to make compile with partial example
```

This would have to be within an expression else it won't work:

```
let mockop x = "Waaaaasup "+(x.ToString())
let realop = mockop // Duplicate definition of value 'realop'
do ...
```

Alternatively, since you are fighting immutability here you could swap over to F#'s OO capabilities:

```
let genericOp (x:'a) = sprintf "hello %A" x
type Container () = 
    member this.GenericOp<'a>(x:'a) = "hello generic " + (x.ToString())
    member val intOp = genericOp with get,set
    member val stringOp = genericOp with get,set

let c = new Container()

printfn "%s" (c.GenericOp "Test")
printfn "%s" (c.GenericOp 1)

printfn "%s" (c.stringOp "Test")
printfn "%s" (c.intOp 1)

let mockOp (x:'a) = sprintf "Mocked %A" x
do c.stringOp <- mockOp
do c.intOp <- mockOp

printfn "%s" (c.stringOp "Test")
printfn "%s" (c.intOp 1)
```

Result is:

```
hello generic Test
hello generic 1
hello "Test"
hello 1
Mocked "Test"
Mocked 1
```

Lastly, you could change your approach and use composition so that you infect the functions you want to mock and then switch between what is injected. Something like:

```
let generic_op (x:'a) = "hello "+(x.ToString())
let int_op (x:int) = "hello "+(x.ToString())
let realInt_op = int_op
let real_op = generic_op
let mock_op x = "Waaaaasup "+(x.ToString())

let doSomething f x =
    do printfn "%s" (f x)

do doSomething realInt_op 1
do doSomething real_op "Real"
do doSomething mock_op "Mock"
```

Comment: Thanks. Shadowing doesn't work because I want to replace **all** calls to mockop. The Container works but requires too much internal code changes (i.e. all realOp => container.realOp) for a temporary effect.  Similarly, composition requires too much internal changes.